# Use emacs to dial a sip phone

Tags: org-mode, bbdb

I remember one thing I liked about Windows 3 in the early 90s was that it was possible to dial my desktop phone (via a modem) from the contacts.  I am all-linux now, and spend most of my day in emacs and have a Cisco SIP phone on my desk at work.  I have always wanted to be able to integrate phone calls in particular into my emacs (and org-mode) workflow.

One step in that direction would be to be able to dial the phone from bbdb or some other emacs-based facility.

Later, getting an org-capture to come up on incoming calls would be great, but one step at a time.

Has anyone heard of any facilities for doing this?  It seems like a natural for emacs, but I am coming up empty in searches.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/231597/command-line-sip-dialer) helps? If the command line tool works, it should be easy to wrap it in an elisp function and use it from emacs.